# I applied Environmental Texture to the object, but I want it only on Suzanne and not on the Glass. How do I do that?

Tags: glass, reflection

So I have been making this model, Suzanne in a Glass. I applied Environmental Texture for some effects but I want them on Suzanne alone and not on the Glass. I want the glass to not reflect the Environmental Texture at all.

Thank You <3

[image]

Comment: can you edit your question to show the shader node trees for the glass and Suzanne?

Comment: Is this the effect you are going for? https://pasteall.org/media/0/8/08ca627234474d8e36780215535c46f7.gif
Removing gloss from glass stops it looking like glass IMO.

Comment: @ Benus, I think he wants reflection of HDRI on some objects only, not all objects

Comment: i think so too.....

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want. @Chris & moonboots I ended up putting everything in a huge cube which fixed my problem but this cube is annoying now.

Answer (score 1):

Having a plain grey background and faking the HDRI reflections on the reflective materials gives you this.

[image]
[image]

Leaving the reflective materials as they are and removing reflections from the World node gives you this. This however removes all reflections, the monkey is only reflective because it's behind glass so it counts as a Transmission ray. Make sure you are in world node editor with the toggle.

[image]
[image]